# Testing two elements with the same text

Tags: cypress

I have a page with two element containing the "some text", but cannot confirm it in my test.

Simplest example is this:

```html
<div>some text</div>
<div>some text</div>
```

```js
const selector = 'div'
const text = 'some text'

cy.get(selector)
  .contains(text)
  .should('have.length', 2);
```

**Cypress log**

> expected  to have a length of 2 but got 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately `.contains()` only ever returns one element. If multiple are found, the first one is returned.

You can instead add `:contains()` into the selector.

Since the selector and text are variables, a string template can build the final selector.

```js
cy.get(`${selector}:contains(${text})`)
  .should('have.length', 2);
```

or put it in a `.filter()`

```js
cy.get(selector)
  .filter(`:contains(${text})`)
  .should('have.length', 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this, using `eq`:

```js
const selector = 'div'
const text = 'some text'
cy.contains(selector, text).eq(0).should('be.visible')
cy.contains(selector, text).eq(1).should('be.visible')
```

Comment: `cy.contains(selector, text).eq(1)` will never pass, that's the point of the question.